# Find out field which does not contain specific value in a column in sql

Tags: sql-server, operators, where-clause

I have table account with the columns `accountnumbers` and `Transactiontype`. One account number will have multiple `transactiontypes`. for example `accountnumber` 12345 will have `transactiontypes` as D,E,C.I wants to find out the accountnumber which does not have the transactiontype D. No matter if it has E or C transactiontypes but if it does not have D transaction, only those particular account number should be captured. Please advise how to acheive this? I have tried the below statement

```
Select accountnumber from table where transactiontype NOT IN('D')
```

but this is picking up the accounts which has transactiontype E and C. i wants to find only accounts where there is no D transations

Comment: Can you rephrase your question? It seems that
```SELECT accountnumber FROM table WHERE transactiontype NOT IN('D')```
already solves your issue of getting records without D. Or you want to get records with E and C, but not D?

Comment: Hi Anton, yes you are right. i want to get record with E and C but not D

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you want a conditional `HAVING` clause:

```sql
SELECT accountnumber
FROM dbo.YourTable
GROUP BY accountnumber
HAVING COUNT(CASE transactiontype WHEN 'D' THEN 1 END) = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

```
declare @x table (accountnumber smallint, transactiontype char(1), tranid int identity(1, 1));

insert @x (accountnumber, transactiontype) values
(1, 'D'), (1, 'C'), (1, 'E'), (1,'F'),
(2, 'E'), (2, 'Z'), 
(3, 'D'),
(4, 'Z');

Select accountnumber from @x 
except
select accountnumber from @x where transactiontype = 'D';
```

And note that this is what YOU should be posting. While handing out suggestions, it is just plain **wrong** that you have a table named "account" that obviously represents something else - maybe account_transactions is a better name. Notice the duplicate filtering. Since your question is not clear and your actual result not defined, I guessed